# How to add popup for comapare products in magento2

Tags: magento2

> app\shop\shop\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\compare\link.phtml

```
<li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare') ?>"
       data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
    >
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare Products') ?>
        <span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

> app\shop\shop\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\compare\list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Compare\ListCompare */
?>
<?php $total = $block->getItems()->getSize() ?>
<div class="compare-popup" id="compare-popup">
<?php if ($total): ?>
    <a href="#" class="action print hidden-print" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Print This Page') ?>">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Print This Page') ?></span>
    </a>
        <div class="table-wrapper comparison">
            <table class="data table table-comparison" id="product-comparison"
                data-mage-init='{"compareList":{
                    "windowPrintSelector":".action.print",
                    "productsInRow":"5",
                    "selectors":{
                        "productAddToCartSelector":"button.action.tocart"}
                }}'>
                <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare Products') ?></caption>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php $index = 0 ?>
                    <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item): ?>
                        <?php if ($index++ == 0): ?>
                            <th scope="row" class="cell label remove"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove Product') ?></span></th>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td class="cell remove product hidden-print">
                            <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare::class);?>
                            <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $compareHelper->getPostDataRemove($item) ?>'
                               class="action delete" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove Product') ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove Product') ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php $index = 0; ?>
                    <?php $helper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class); ?>
                    <?php /** @var $item \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                    <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item): ?>
                        <?php if ($index++ == 0): ?>
                            <th scope="row" class="cell label product"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product') ?></span></th>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product')) ?>" class="cell product info">
                            <a class="product-item-photo" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->stripTags($item->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                                <?= $block->getImage($item, 'product_comparison_list')->toHtml() ?>
                            </a>
                            <strong class="product-item-name">
                                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($item) ?>" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->stripTags($item->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helper->productAttribute($item, $item->getName(), 'name') ?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($item, 'short') ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($item, '-compare-list-top') ?>
                            <div class="product-item-actions hidden-print">
                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                    <?php if ($item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare::class)->getAddToCartUrl($item) ?>" method="post">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit" class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <?php if ($item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class)->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                        <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($item) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist">
                                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($block->getAttributes() as $attribute): ?>
                    <?php $index = 0; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->hasAttributeValueForProducts($attribute)): ?>
                         <tr>
                            <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $item): ?>
                                <?php if ($index++ == 0): ?>
                                    <th scope="row" class="cell label">
                                        <span class="attribute label">
                                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($attribute->getStoreLabel() ? $attribute->getStoreLabel() : __($attribute->getFrontendLabel())) ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </th>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <td class="cell product attribute">
                                    <div class="attribute value">
                                        <?php switch ($attribute->getAttributeCode()) {
                                            case "price": ?>
                                                <?php
                                                    /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice(
                                                        $item,
                                                        '-compare-list-' . $attribute->getCode()
                                                    )
                                                ?>
                                                <?php break;
                                            case "small_image": ?>
                                                <?php $block->getImage($item, 'product_small_image')->toHtml(); ?>
                                                <?php break;
                                            default: ?>
                                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helper->productAttribute($item, $block->getProductAttributeValue($item, $attribute), $attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
                                            <?php break;
                                        } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "[data-role=tocart-form]": {
                    "catalogAddToCart": {}
                }
            }
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have no items to compare.') ?></div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<script>
require(
      [
          'jquery',
          'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
      ],
      function($,modal) {
           $('li.item.link.compare').click(function(event){
             alert("hi");
          var options = {
              type: 'popup',
              responsive: true,
              innerScroll: false,
              modalClass: 'compare-products',
              buttons: [{

                  class: '',
                  click: function () {
                      this.closeModal();
                  }
              }]
          };

          var popup = modal(options, $('.comparepopup'));

          $('.comparepopup').modal('openModal');
      });
  });

</script>
```

In js file i added this script , when click on item link compare popup is not openaning , showing like nodename not found..  please tell me how to add popup for compare products